# Paid for motorcycle via credit card, NO dealer documents signed yet and bike has NOT been delivered yet, can i back out?

Tags: credit, california, payment, documents

I want to back out of a purchase of a small motorcycle, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

We processed my credit card info to cover the purchase price and taxes on the vehicle 39 hours ago, and now I'd like to no longer continue with the purchase.

It has not been delivered, and no documentation has been signed yet, the docs are either going to be mailed, or come with the bike (haven't finalized which yet). They don't even have a copy of my license yet.

Can I back out, or am I still stuck due to paying for the bike?

I am in California and I have also not even stepped onto the dealership floor, everything was conducted over the phone, and it is a used bike, not new.

Comment: What happened when you phoned the dealer and asked to back out?

Comment: They aren't open yet, which is why I posted here. I'm hoping to get an idea of what to expect before making the call. if no one answers within a couple hours I'll just call in blind and find out myself.
I'll let you know what happens if you're interested.

Comment: You may not have physically signed anything, but agreeing to pay with your credit card may be the equivalent of a verbal contract to purchase the bike. At this point, it may not be a question of whether you can back out, but if you can *return* your bike.

Comment: Just call the dealer when they open. The answer is either "yes, you can back out", in which case that's what you'll do, or "no, you can't", in which case you need to find out if you can return your new bike.

Comment: I think you can cancel, but Law.SE would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Did you give them your credit card without seeing the motorcycle or testing it?

Comment: Yes because multiple people had already called in for it, if I hadn't I would have for sure been unable to get it at all. It only has 109 miles on it so I know it hasn't been run down.

Answer (score 3):

The law is a mixture of state and federal law.

From [California](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/brochures/fast_facts/ffvr35):

> **Used Car Buyers**
>
> Consumers who purchase a used car for less than $40,000 must be
>   offered a two-day contract cancellation option agreement.
>
> NOTE: There is no "cooling off" period unless you purchase a contract
>   cancellation option agreement.
>
> EXCEPTION: The contract cancellation option agreement does not apply
>   to used cars priced at $40,000 or more, new cars, private party sales,
>   motorcycles, off-highway vehicles, recreational vehicles, or vehicles
>   sold for business or commercial use (does not include pickup trucks
>   purchased for personal use).

The FTC has [information on buying a used car](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0055-buying-used-car):

> Dealers are not required by federal law to give used car buyers a
>   three-day right to cancel. In some states, dealers are required to
>   give a right to cancel. In other states, the right to return the car
>   in a few days for a refund exists only if the dealer chooses to offer
>   this privilege. Dealers may describe the right to cancel as a
>   "cooling-off" period, a money-back guarantee, or a "no questions
>   asked" return policy. Before you buy from a dealer, ask about the
>   dealer's return policy, get it in writing, and read it carefully.

I asked in the comments:

> "Did you give them your credit card without seeing the motorcycle or
>   testing it?"

The answer was:

> "Yes because multiple people had already called in for it, if I hadn't
>   I would have for sure been unable to get it at all. It only has 109
>   miles on it so I know it hasn't been run down."

The issue for the dealer will be that they turned others away based on your giving them a credit card. They could have sold it anytime between when you paid for it, and when you called to cancel.

That credit card transaction has to be considered binding. If the tables were turned you would sue them if they sold it to somebody else who showed up with cash in hand. You would sue for specific performance of the contract.

You can hope that they think it will sell quickly, and they only charge you a restocking fee.

Comment: Have you bought it if you haven't signed the purchase documents, or taken delivery of the bike?

Comment: "Have you bought it if you haven't signed the purchase documents, or taken delivery of the bike?" That's kind of the concise question I guess I'm trying to get an answer for.

Comment: To mHoran, appreciate the input! My only issue is that the above deals with signed contracts, while I have nothing signed. I'm hoping for someone to shed some light on that finer detail.

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate all the responses, I did end up calling the dealer and they did refund the full amount. I learned through making some phone calls all around the area that each dealer has its own policy. This one's policy is to provide a full refund.

Keep the refund policy in mind when it comes to the buying a motorcycle because it seems as long as nothing has been signed, all places should have the option to provide a full refund.

Hope this helps someone out in the future!